# Solr secure admin panel

Tags: solr

I have setup Solr (v 4.2.1) for one of my websites and I am having trouble securing the admin panel
I am running Solr with Jetty. I did not use tomcat
I have edited example/etc/jetty.xml and modified the host value to read

```
<Call name="addConnector">
      <Arg>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
            <Set name="host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host" default="10.100.202.42"/></Set>
            <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8983"/></Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">50000</Set>
            <Set name="lowResourceMaxIdleTime">1500</Set>
            <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
          </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
```

I start the server and it binds to

```
::ffff:10.100.202.42:8983
```

However, I am able to access the admin panel by using the site's external IP. 
Am I missing something?

Thanks